# Add LayoutAnchorable programmatically on AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I'm trying to add a new Control to AvalonDock from code.
Here`s the code:

```
var test = new LayoutAnchorable();
test.Title = "teste";
test.IsActive = true;
test.IsSelected = true;
test.ContentId = "search12";
test.Content = new TextBox();
test.AddToLayout(dockingManager, AnchorableShowStrategy.Right);
```

The new panel shows up, but the Content doesn't (just gray panel).
Why?

Comment: adding Layoutanchorables by code is disabled when binding Documents hence it is not possible to bind documents but handle other views manually

Comment: I try this code in Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit Plus version 2.5 and it works correctly "as is". It seems that the issue was fixed during revisions at least in the AValonDock that is included in this package.